# For loop properly toggling some tabs, but not all

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm working on a portfolio website to show at an upcoming internship interview. I'm trying to make the resume page tabbed: one tab for highlights, one for work experience, one for education, and one for references. I've been using [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) and [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp) on the w3schools website to get this far, but despite following the tutorial there, two of my tabs aren't displaying properly.

The "Highlights" and "Work History" tabs work properly: they display the correct tab content, and the current tab button/link is properly highlighted. The "Highlights" tab also displays when the page is first loaded, as intended. However, the "Education" and "References" tabs display no content whatsoever. The current tab button/link is still highlighted properly, so that is no issue.

My guess is that there is some problem in the for loop I'm using to toggle "display: none" and "display: block", but I can't quite put my finger on the exact issue. The for loop that assigns a tab to "active" in order to change the color of the current tab seems to be working just fine. This is my first time working with tabs, so I'm not as familiar with them as I'd like.

A secondary issue, which I'm less concerned about, is that the "Highlights" button isn't highlighted when the page first loads, even though that tab's content displays on page load, as intended.

I really appreciate any help you folks can offer!

```
<head>
<style>
.tab    {overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #AE7B68;
        background-color: #AE7B68; padding: 6px 12px;}

.tab button {background-color: #AE7B68; float: left; 
            border: 1px solid #244628;
            outline: none; cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px; transition: 0.3s; font-size: 17px;}

.tab button:hover   {background-color: #EE8F0A;}

.tab button.active  {background-color: #EE8F0A;}

.tabcontent {margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;
            padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #AE7B68;
            border: 1px solid #AE7B68; border-top: none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <div class="tab"> 
        <button class="tablinks" 
        onclick="openRes(event, 'Highlights')"
        id="defaultOpen">Highlights</button>
        <button class="tablinks"
        onclick="openRes(event, 'Work')">Work History</button>
        <button class="tablinks"
        onclick="openRes(event, 'Education')">Education</button>
        <button class="tablinks"
        onclick="openRes(event, 'References')">References</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Highlights" class="tabcontent">
        CONTENT     
    </div>
    <div id="Work" class="tabcontent">
        CONTENT
    <div>
    <div id="Education" class="tabcontent">
        CONTENT    
    </div>
    <div id="References" class="tabcontent">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <script>
        function openRes(evt, resPart)
        {
            document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
            var i, x, tablinks;
            // Hide all elements of class "tabcontent"
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            //Remove "active" class from tab links
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)
            {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(resPart).style.display = "block";
            //Add "active" to current tab link so it's highlighted
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
    </script>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close one `</div>` properly (your Work tab). https://jsfiddle.net/amfwe17j/4/ - these kinds of issues happen often, so I suggest validating your HTML on https://validator.w3.org/ to fix HTML issues, because many times these are the root of the problem.

To show a tab by default, search for **Show a tab by default** in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp - they explain how to get your default tab open/highlighted, which you should do.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe the answer was so simple -- but I guess it often is for beginning programmers. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome. With over a decade of experience it happens to me too! Get used to it :)